# How to get Google Apps Script to tell Google Docs to bold, italic, strikethrough and underline from a JSON representation?

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I have written a function, `setParagraphToRichText` which accepts a GoogleAppsScript.Document.Paragraph and a string. The string is a stringified JSON blob that defines the text and attributes of a given paragraph.

```
/**
 *
 *
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Document.Paragraph} paragraph
 * @param {string} jsonString
 */
function setParagraphToRichText(paragraph, jsonString) {
  const text = paragraph.editAsText();
  const json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  const texts = json.runs.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
                                 return accumulator + current.text;
                                 }, "");
  text.setText(texts);
  for (let i = 0; i < json.runs.length; i++) {
    const run = json.runs[i];
    if (run.endIndex >= texts.length) run.endIndex--;
    text.setLinkUrl(run.startIndex, run.endIndex, run.linkUrl)
    .setBold(run.startIndex, run.endIndex, run.isBold)
    .setItalic(run.startIndex, run.endIndex, run.isItalic)
    .setStrikethrough(run.startIndex, run.endIndex, run.isStrikethrough)
    .setUnderline(run.startIndex, run.endIndex, run.isUnderline)
    .setFontFamily(run.startIndex, run.endIndex, run.textStyle.fontFamily)
    .setFontSize(run.startIndex, run.endIndex, run.textStyle.fontSize)
    .setForegroundColor(run.startIndex, run.endIndex, run.textStyle.foregroundColour);
  }
}
```

That's how it looks in Google Apps Script itself. The original is in Typescript.

I test that code with the following:

```
function myFunction() {
  const body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  const paragraphs = body.getParagraphs();
  const obj = {
    "runs": [{
            "endIndex": 4,
            "startIndex": 0,
            "text": "dog ",
            "textStyle": {
                "fontFamily": "Arial",
                "fontSize": 10,
                "foregroundColour": "#1155cc",
                "foregroundColor": "#1155cc",
                "isBold": false,
                "isItalic": false,
                "isStrikethrough": false,
                "isUnderline": true
            },
            "linkUrl": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog"
        }, {
            "endIndex": 8,
            "startIndex": 4,
            "text": "cat ",
            "textStyle": {
                "fontFamily": "Arial",
                "fontSize": 10,
                "foregroundColour": "#000000",
                "foregroundColor": "#000000",
                "isBold": true,
                "isItalic": false,
                "isStrikethrough": false,
                "isUnderline": false
            },
            "linkUrl": null
        }, {
            "endIndex": 12,
            "startIndex": 8,
            "text": "cow ",
            "textStyle": {
                "fontFamily": "Arial",
                "fontSize": 10,
                "foregroundColour": "#000000",
                "foregroundColor": "#000000",
                "isBold": false,
                "isItalic": true,
                "isStrikethrough": false,
                "isUnderline": false
            },
            "linkUrl": null
        }, {
            "endIndex": 16,
            "startIndex": 12,
            "text": "bat ",
            "textStyle": {
                "fontFamily": "Arial",
                "fontSize": 10,
                "foregroundColour": "#000000",
                "foregroundColor": "#000000",
                "isBold": false,
                "isItalic": false,
                "isStrikethrough": true,
                "isUnderline": false
            },
            "linkUrl": null
        }, {
            "endIndex": 20,
            "startIndex": 16,
            "text": "fox ",
            "textStyle": {
                "fontFamily": "Arial",
                "fontSize": 10,
                "foregroundColour": "#fbbc04",
                "foregroundColor": "#fbbc04",
                "isBold": false,
                "isItalic": false,
                "isStrikethrough": false,
                "isUnderline": false
            },
            "linkUrl": null
        }, {
            "endIndex": 24,
            "startIndex": 20,
            "text": "jay ",
            "textStyle": {
                "fontFamily": "Impact",
                "fontSize": 10,
                "foregroundColour": "#000000",
                "foregroundColor": "#000000",
                "isBold": false,
                "isItalic": false,
                "isStrikethrough": false,
                "isUnderline": false
            },
            "linkUrl": null
        }, {
            "endIndex": 27,
            "startIndex": 24,
            "text": "kit",
            "textStyle": {
                "fontFamily": "Arial",
                "fontSize": 36,
                "foregroundColour": "#000000",
                "foregroundColor": "#000000",
                "isBold": false,
                "isItalic": false,
                "isStrikethrough": false,
                "isUnderline": false
            },
            "linkUrl": null
        }
    ]
};

  setParagraphToRichText(paragraphs[0], JSON.stringify(obj))
}
```

By rights, I should get `dog cat cow bat fox jay kit` where `dog` has a linkUrl, `cat` is bold, `cow` is italic, `bat` is strikethrough-ed, `fox` is in ACCENT3-colour, `jay` is in Impact-font and `kit` is in 36-point.

However, what I get is everything right EXCEPT `cat`, `cow` and `bat` which are not in the aforementioned styles.

Where have I gone wrong? The documentation for [bold](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setboldstartoffset,-endoffsetinclusive,-bold) seems pretty self-explanatory and I'm fairly sure I'm following it.

(And yes, I speak a minority dialect of English that puts `u` into words where other dialects don't.)

**NEXT DAY**

Thanks to [Oleg Valter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11407695/oleg-valter) for pointing out my typo. So, very embarrassingly, the issue turns out not to be with Google but with me.

Comment: shouldn't it be `run.textStyle.isBold`, `run.textStyle.isItalic`, etc? Btw, a side note - could you clarify why do you stringify and then immediately parse the JSON object - is this for a unit test of a function you intend to use in a Web App or with `PropertiesService`?

Comment: Thanks, @OlegValter, for pointing that out. Sigh. As for the stringify and parse, that was just for testing.

Comment: happens :) If you were using the online editor - switch to a local IDE, I think this would not be possible with good autocompletion. Re:JSON - ok, was just curious why such a peculiar setup